# Sort array and return initial index VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting, indexing

So this might be an easy one but I just couldn't work my head around it.I am working on VBA.

I have the following array:
    `temp=(9,4,9,3,8,4,9,8)`

and i want to sort it but instead of returning

`temp=(9,9,9,8,8,4,4,3)`

i want it to return the index of the value like

`temp=(1,3,7,5,8,2,6,4)`.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim arr, v, i, arr2()
    arr = Array(9, 4, 9, 3, 8, 4, 9, 8)
    ReDim arr2(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr))

    Debug.Print "Original", Join(arr, ",")

    For i = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        arr2(i) = Application.Large(arr, i + 1)
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Sorted", Join(arr2, ",")

    For i = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        v = Application.Match(arr2(i), arr, 0)
        arr2(i) = v 'save the position
        arr(v - 1) = vbNull 'remove the found value
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Positions", Join(arr2, ",")

End Sub
```

EDIT: without the intermediate sort

```
Sub Tester2()

    Dim arr, v, i, arr2()

    arr = Array(9, 4, 9, 3, 8, 4, 9, 8)
    ReDim arr2(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr))

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        v = Application.Match(Application.Large(arr, 1), arr, 0)
        arr(v - 1) = vbNull
        arr2(i) = v
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Positions", Join(arr2, ",")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I will alter it and add it to my program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another algo using only native VBA functions, i.e. no Excel functions such as Application.Match etc., which should be much faster for large arrays. Takes about 5 seconds for an array of ca. 9000 elements. It returns the array of indices `sort_idx` as well as the array of sorted values `arr_sorted`. Note: the array here is 2D with any number of rows and 1 column, taken from column A on sheet "1". Can be easily adapted for a 1D array.

```
Sub cost_min()

    'Get data
    arr = Range(Sheets("1").Range("A1"), Sheets("1").Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Value2
    
    'Sort price curve & get indices
    Dim sort_idx(), arr_sorted()
    ReDim sort_idx(1 To UBound(arr)), arr_sorted(1 To UBound(arr))
    arr_2 = arr 'create copy to edit while sorting
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    
        'Get max, record idx & value
        max_val = arr_2(1, 1)
        j = 1
        sort_idx(i) = j
        arr_sorted(i) = max_val
        
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr_2)
        
            If arr_2(j, 1) > max_val Then
                max_val = arr_2(j, 1)
                sort_idx(i) = j
                arr_sorted(i) = max_val
            End If
               
        Next j
        
        'Replace max found with null
        arr_2(sort_idx(i), 1) = vbNull
        
    Next i

 End Sub
```